# Htmlunitdriver not able to open page which is based on sockets

Tags: java, sockets, selenium, selenium-webdriver, htmlunit-driver

Code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver webDriver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);
    webDriver.get("https://www.crowdchat.net/chat/c3BvdF9vYmpfMjE2MQ==");
}
```

URL: https://www.crowdchat.net/chat/c3BvdF9vYmpfMjE2MQ==

Above code is working fine with FirefoxDriver. If I try to open this url using htmlUnitDriver, it is showing some errors. What could be the solution for this problem? Do I need to set something like proxy? Please help.
browser version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.52.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:      com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "console" is not defined. (script in https://www.crowdchat.net/chat/c3BvdF9vYmpfMjE2MQ== from (1, 2033) to (2, 53)#1)
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd10cf2c0560f637404c2d96164b67d9d67', time: '2015-10-09 13:08:06'
System info: host: 'v-lm', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-24-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_79'
Driver info: driver.version: HtmlUnitDriver
at  org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:554)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:530)
at net.crowdchat.test.post.test.main(test.java:13)
Caused by: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException:    ReferenceError: "console" is not defined. (script in https://www.crowdchat.net/chat/c3BvdF9vYmpfMjE2MQ== from (1, 2033) to (2, 53)#1)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:865)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:628)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:513)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:747)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:722)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:945)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeInlineScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:351)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:411)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$3.execute(HtmlScript.java:270)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:290)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:800)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:757)
at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1170)
at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1072)
at org.cyberneko.html.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:206)
at org.cyberneko.html.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:330)
at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3126)
at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2093)
at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:920)
at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:499)
at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:452)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:1040)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:253)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:199)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:272)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:160)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:476)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:350)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:415)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:541)
... 2 more
Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "console" is not defined. (script in https://www.crowdchat.net/chat/c3BvdF9vYmpfMjE2MQ== from (1, 2033) to (2, 53)#1)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3935)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3919)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFoundError(ScriptRuntime.java:3996)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.name(ScriptRuntime.java:1846)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1627)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:798)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:411)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:310)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3286)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:115)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:738)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:850)
```

Comment: You should try with `new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.CHROME)`..hope it will help you..:)

Comment: Are you getting same error?

Comment: upgrade your selenium version to 2.53.0..